# Oracle Transactions PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, transactions, procedure

I am working on PLSQL based Procedures in Oracle 11g & 12c.

I want to keep logs of table name and row count when I issue commit command in one of my procedure/function.

This is for audit logs.

Can you please suggest how do I accomplish this?

Comment: This may help.  https://www.foxinfotech.in/2018/09/how-to-create-log-file-in-oracle-using-pl-sql.html

Answer (score 2):

Your PL/SQL code will need to keep track of its activity and log it.  There is no way to ask Oracle "how many rows are you committing right now and to which tables?"

So, e.g.,

```
DECLARE
  l_row_count NUMBER; 
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_1 SET column_a = 'whatever' WHERE column_b = 'some condition';

  l_row_count := SQL%ROWCOUNT;

  INSERT INTO my_audit ( action, cnt ) VALUES ('Updated table_1', l_row_count);
  -- Notice the audit is part of the transaction; if I don't commit the UPDATE,
  -- I won't commit the log of the update.

  -- ... do other similar updates / inserts / deleted, using SQL%ROWCOUNT to 
  -- to determine the number of rows affected and log each one ...

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Again, it is not practical to do a bunch of DML statements (inserts, updates, deletes) and then ask Oracle after the fact "what I have done so far in this transaction?"  You need to record it as you go.